# AddLine: adding values to coordinates creates invalid procedure error

Tags: vba, autocad

I can create lines perfectly fine, but for my scenario it would be more efficient to use all similar points but add additional values to my x or y coordinates.

below line1 works fine. but I had to set up individual variables, and if i have a few hundred lines its going to get messy. which is why id prefer something like "testline" over "line1".

```
Dim basePnt As Variant
basePnt = ThisDrawing.Utility.GetPoint(, "select base")

Dim topdoorpoint As Variant
topdoorpoint = basePnt

Dim displacepoint As Variant
displacepoint = basePnt
displacepoint(1) = displacepoint(1) + DOORHEIGHT ' Shift up by fullheight of doorheight, y coordinate

'line1 works great
Dim line1 As AcadLine
Set line1 = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddLine(displacepoint, topdoorpoint)

'testline revieves error;invalid procedure call or argument, run time error "5"
Set testline = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddLine(basePnt, Array(basePnt(0), basePnt(1) + DOORHEIGHT, basePnt(2)))
```

one thing i tried:
Set testline = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddLine(Array(0, 0, 0), Array(1000, 1000, 0))
i ran this as a test to see if my variables were the issue, but it seems it lies more within me using incorrect syntax. above also had the same run time error.

Comment: Where is `DOORHEIGHT` defined? What is its value?

Comment: its on a userform, value is 84 but can be different per user input. it works and doesnt cause any issues.

Comment: AutoCAD is very picky about variable types. Maybe the `Array` function is returning something other than a Variant array of Doubles when you add another number to it? Not 100% sure but I recall being frustrated by something similar and the problem was that mine was converted to an array of `Singles` instead of `Doubles` due to some math I was doing to them.

Comment: Long shot, but maybe make sure `DOORHEIGHT` is defined as a `Double` and not something like an `Integer` or `Single`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. doorheight is define as Double. upon further research, it seems like you just cannot edit coordinates like the way i am describing. If it is truly possible, there doesn't seem to be any documentation regarding that on their website. dead end here lol.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is just

```
Dim px As Variant
px = basePnt
px(1) = px(1) + DOORHEIGHT
Set testline = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddLine(basePnt, px)
```

Declared in this way `Dim px As Variant` we have a variant of `Doubles`.

But if we us it like this:

```
Dim px1 As Variant
px1 = Array(basePnt(0), basePnt(1) + DOORHEIGHT, basePnt(2))
```

We have variant of variants of doubles (You can check that on the Watches window) - so we have type mismatch.